# Heroku msnodesqlv8 problem - Error while deploying

Tags: node.js, sql-server, heroku, deployment, prebuild

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku but keep getting this error and i couldn't find the solution.
My database is already on a server and can connect without a problem.

> -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
> -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
> -----> Node.js app detected
>
> -----> Creating runtime environment
>
> ```
>    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>    USE_YARN_CACHE=true
>    NODE_VERBOSE=false
>    NODE_ENV=production
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
> ```
>
> -----> Installing binaries
> engines.node (package.json):  16.1.0
> engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
> engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
>
> ```
>    Resolving node version 16.1.0...
>    Downloading and installing node 16.1.0...
>    Using default npm version: 7.11.2
>    Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
>    Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
>    Installed yarn 1.22.10
> ```
>
> -----> Installing dependencies
> Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
> yarn install v1.22.10
> [1/4] Resolving packages...
> [2/4] Fetching packages...
> [3/4] Linking dependencies...
> [4/4] Building fresh packages...
> error /tmp/build_513662c2/node_modules/msnodesqlv8: Command failed.
> Exit code: 1
> Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
> Arguments:
> Directory: /tmp/build_513662c2/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
> Output:
> (node:801) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_513662c2/node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build'
> CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sqlserverv8/src/ConnectionHandles.o
> In file included from ../src/ConnectionHandles.h:22,
> from ../src/ConnectionHandles.cpp:1:
> ../src/stdafx.h:37:14: fatal error: sqltypes.h: No such file or directory
> 37 |     #include <sqltypes.h>
> |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [sqlserverv8.target.mk:164: Release/obj.target/sqlserverv8/src/ConnectionHandles.o] Error 1
> make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_513662c2/node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build'
> gyp ERR! build error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_513662c2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws
> gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_513662c2/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_513662c2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_513662c2/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
> gyp ERR! node -v v16.1.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
> gyp ERR! not ok
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
> -----> Build failed
>
> ```
>    We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>    
>    If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
>    https://help.heroku.com/
>    
>    Love,
>    Heroku
>      !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed
> ```

I think its something about "msnodesqlv8" because when i delete it from package.json everything seems to be working fine and app can be deployed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Linux requires installing Microsoft drivers for SQL Server.

See the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15